# Proper convention for handling the stack when managing parameters and the return address

Tags: assembly, 68hc12

What is the best way to handle having the return address of a calling function on top of any parameters that have been placed in the stack when you need to access parameters 'below' it in the stack? I am using the S12 Motorola/Freescale processor. (The S12 has: D register with 16 bits consisting of A and B registers each of which has 8 bits. X and Y index registers each 16 bits, a program counter and a stack pointer) A sample of the code is:

```
MAIN ORG    $1500        ;Set the start of the program 
     LDD    #SomeValue   ;Load the D register with a value
     PSHD                ;Push D onto the stack
     JSR    ROUTINE      ;Go to the subroutine - pushes the PC to the SP
END_MAIN    END

ROUTINE     
     PULD                ;Pull the top of the stack into the D register
                         ;D now holds the address for returning to the 
                         ;main function. 
     PSHD                ;Push the return address back onto the stack
END_ROUTINE RTS          ;Return to Main routine
```

The problem is that the top of the stack holds the address for the next instruction which makes it difficult to maneuver around. For example, if I needed a parameter that is underneath the the address, I would have to either manually adjust the SP (which seems rather hacky) or I will have to pull the top of the stack off and store it in a register which takes up space. A twist on the last approach is to store the return address in a variable, unfortunately, the variables declared here are global in scope, which does not feel ideal.

```
ReturnAddress EQU $2000        ;Declare variable at address $2000
STD           ReturnAddress    ;Store the D register's contents in variable
```

Is there another option which I am not seeing here?

Comment: Using other architectures the trick is to access the stack relative to the stack pointer, do you have such an addressing mode? Quick googling says yes, you can do something like `LDAA 4, SP`.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, I think so. In order to do that, I believe that the stack has to be loaded into one of the index registers first.  EDIT With that being the case, would one access the desired parameters within the subroutine, and then pop them off the stack once the original routine is resumed?

Comment: Consult your manual, what I googled explicitly says you can use `SP`.

Comment: [Using the stack pointer as an indexing register in all indexed operations](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/data-sheets/MC9S12P128.pdf)

Comment: Cheers, I am just now learning assembly and I guess was having trouble articulating what exactly it was I was looking for. So RTFM was not exactly my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some input from Jester, it is fairly simple to be able to observe what is happening in the stack and to use parameters contained therein. I wrote a simple program that demonstrates passing parameters by value and reference.

```
QUOTIENT    EQU     $1000       ;Variable to hold our QUOTIENT
REMAINDER   EQU     $1002       ;Variable to hold our REMAINDER

MAIN        ORG     $2000       ;Set the start of the program
            LDD     #!50        ;Load the D register with a value (16 bits)
            PSHD                ;Push D onto the stack (16 bits)
            LDD     #!10        ;Load the D register with a value (16 bits)
            PSHD                ;Push D onto the stack (16 bits)
            LDD     #QUOTIENT   ;Load the D register with an address (16 bits)
            PSHD                ;Push D onto the stack (16 bits)
            LDD     #REMAINDER  ;Load the D register with an address (16 bits)
            PSHD                ;Push D onto the stack (16 bits)
            JSR     DIVIDE      ;Push the PC onto the stack (16 bits).
            LEAS $0A, SP         ;Instead of PULD 5x, thanks Jester
END_MAIN    END


;******************************************************************************;
;DIVIDE - This routine expects the following parameters to be on the stack:
; STACK
;( 0 ) - (16 bits for return address)
;( 2 ) - (16 bits of address to store the REMAINDER (ANSWER var reference))
;( 4 ) - (16 bits of address to store the QUOTIENT (ANSWER var reference))
;( 6 ) - (16 bits for divisor)
;( 8 ) - (16 bits for dividend)
;******************************************************************************;
DIVIDE      LDD     8,SP       ;Loads the dividend (50)
            LDX     6,SP       ;Loads the divisor (10)
            IDIV               ;Divide
            LDY     4,SP       ;Get the address of the Quotient
            STX     0,Y        ;Store at that address
            LDY     2,SP       ;Get the address of the remainder
            STD     0,Y        ;Store at that address
END_DIVIDE  RTS
```

Comment: Note that you usually discard items from the stack by adjusting the stack pointer. The five `PULD` instructions are normally written as `LEAS 10, SP`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!